# React router v6 useNavigate hook - state is null when using -1 to go back

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In react-router v6, to go back `navigate(-1)` has to be used.

```js
const navigate = useNavigate()
...
navigate(-1)
```

But typescript does not accepts a `number` (-1)

```js
export interface NavigateFunction {
    (to: To, options?: NavigateOptions): void;
    (delta: number): void;
}
export type To = string | Partial<Path>;
export declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
```

so I use this and **navigation works fine**.

```js
navigate(-1 as To)
```

But, I need to pass a state along with navigation. I use `useLocation` hook to access the passed state from `useNavigate`.

**The problem is the state is always `null`** when I use **-1** to navigate back.
It seeems to work fine when

```js
navigate("/", {state: {animate: false}})
```

**But not**

```js
navigate(-1 as To, {state: {animate: false}})
```

**Note:** the data passed is a just a object and JSON serializable. only when it is not the state will be null